# Convert pdf,doc,ppt,xls files to html using php

Tags: php

Actually I want all files view as html like gmail in view as html.

I have used below code for doc view as html but here not displaying font style  (bold,color,etc...)

```
function parseWord($userDoc) 
{
    $fileHandle = fopen($userDoc, "r");
    $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($userDoc));   
    $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
    $outtext = "";
    foreach($lines as $thisline)
      {
        $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
        if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
          {
          } else {
            $outtext .= $thisline." ";
          }
      }
     $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
    return $outtext;
} 

$userDoc = "cv.doc";

$text = parseWord($userDoc);
echo $text;

?>
```

Is there any way to view all files as html for display in browser?
I am not interested in use plugins and any s/w.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function available in PHP. You'll have to do everything on your own or rely on some software.

If you change your mind about foreign software let us know.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few free tools that you can use to parse such documents. Take a look [here](http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php). There are even tools that convert doc and pdf sources directly into html, but we have never tested those. Google [here](http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Ade%3Aofficial&hs=WVI&q=php+convert+word+to+html&btnG=Suche&meta=)

Comment: Thank u Andre and Olaf for reply :)
I am new in php. This  concept i am used for my new website. So can i install that tools / S/w on server? And i think, i have not rights to install that tools on server. So what can i do?

Is there any library folder so we can upload on server and use it?

Comment: Indeed, you need certain rights to install and run those tools on the server (they are executables). However, Virtual Linux servers get cheaper all the time, and there you can install whatever you want (although you need quite a bit of knowledge for that). You can also ask the hosting provider to do it for you (they may or may not). But if you want to do advanced stuff, you need advanced tools. There may also be php libs somewhere to be found, but I do not know of them. Try Google.